# Hello am just a beginner with ubuntu 19.4, but i have already fallen in errors while trying to install netbeans and LAMP

Tags: lamp, netbeans

Entiry this was after doing a system upgrade and i repeatitively keep getting this error when ever i try to install any software, what should  i do

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 apache2 : Depends: apache2-bin (= 2.4.38-2ubuntu2.3) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: apache2-utils (=2.4.38-2ubuntu2.3)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Thats the case for installing apache,

and fetch errors when updating

Comment: First "19.4" isn't a Ubuntu version, did you mean "19.04", the April, 2019 release?

Comment: yes 19.04, am sorry for that error

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be telling you that, in addition to `apache2`, you need to install the `apache2-bin` and `apache2-utils` packages.

I'd also suggest installing `apache2-doc`, the Apache documentation package.

After installation, you can use `dpkg -L packagename` to see what files are in the package.

Comment: how do i install apache2-bin and apache2-utils, i thought sudo apt-get install apache2, installs everything